# Javascript: Calculating from object properties

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following objects:

```
const circle = { center: { x: 0, y: 0 }, radius: 10 };
const point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
```

And I need to determine whether point lies in a circle. My code is:

```
function isInsideCircle(circle, point) {
  if (((point.x - circle.center.x) * (point.x - circle.center.x) + (point.y - circle.center.y) * (point.y - circle.center.y)) <= circle.radius * circle.radius) return true;
  return false;
}
```

But this does not work at all. The testing environment says, that it returns wrong boolean, so I suppose it doesn't calculate at all. Am I accessing objects properties wrongly?

Comment: "This does not work at all". Please describe the not working part as detailed as possible in advance. This way people can help you easier instead of figuring out the problem in the first place.

Also, if you make your code more readable by using variables with a meaningful name for each part of your calculation, you will make everyones life easier :)

Comment: I copied your code and ran it.
I think the code works fine.
When the center of the circle is (0,0) and the radius is 10
Point is (0,0) returns true.
When the center of the circle is (0,0) and the radius is 10
Point is (15,15) returns false.
So I'm not quite sure what your question is referring to